# Firebird stored procedure array datatypes

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I'm trying to solve a problem in a Firebird stored procedure.  I need to read some records from a table, (FOR SELECT...BEGIN   END) and, after changing things around, INSERT some of them back into the same table (new record), within the BEGIN END loop.

- Unless I misunderstand it, the simplest way would be to use a cursor, but I just can't find out how to do it, either by trial and error, or from the internet.
- Another approach would be to use an in-memory array (not a table datatype, but a PSQL datatype declared in the stored procedure). The problem is the same as above.
- The third seems to be to use a Global Temporary Table - unfortunately it seems that they can't be used in a single SQL statement with 'normal' tables, so I can't copy the results to the original table.
- The final approach is to create a table and use it as an intermediary - I just don't like this approach. I'll do it if there's no other solution

In short, can anyone help me with how to select some rows from a table (with other tables in the selection), and write back to the same table?

thanks

steve

ps doing just FOR SELECT BEGIN... INSERT ... END results in a never ending loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cursor you can do it with simple PSQL code using [`DECLARE CURSOR`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-declare-cursor).